# Libgit2sharp Unit Test

Tags: c#, git, unit-testing, libgit2sharp

I am currently using libgit2sharp and i was wondering how to correctly unit test my methods there. I heard unit tests should be independent, but how should I archive that?

Right now I have three methods:

```
Stage, Commit, Push.
```

Now if I want to write a unit test for push, i have to stage and commit first, but it doesn't seem right to call two methods before testing the actual method.

I read some things about Moq but I couldn't find any examples on how to mock libgit2sharp.

Thanks in advance